# "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: " Why am I getting this error message?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html, etree
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium. webdriver. chrome. options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selectorlib import Extractor
import os
from datetime import date
import shutil
import requests
import json

#hey
# os.system("cat banner.txt")
today = date.today() #get todays date for the output file
date = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
print('\n')

search_query = input('Enter an item: ')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options. add_experimental_option("detach", True)

def search_amazon(item):

    s=Service('V:\Python Project\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

    # driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox")
    # search_button = search_box.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"nav-search-submit-text").click()
    search_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nav-search-submit-text").click()
    driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)


    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    try:
        num_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-pagination")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        num_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-last").click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    url_list = []

    for i in range(int(num_page.text)):
        page_ = i + 1
        url_list.append(driver.current_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(4)
        click_next = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'a-last').click()
        print("Page " + str(page_) + " grabbed")

    driver.quit()


    with open('search_results_urls.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        for result_page in url_list:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % result_page)

    print("---DONE GRABBING LINKS---")

def scrape(url):

    headers = {
        'dnt': '1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'referer': 'https://www.amazon.com/',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }

    # Download the page using requests
    print("Downloading %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Simple check to check if page was blocked (Usually 503)
    if r.status_code > 500:
        if "To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact" in r.text:
            print("Page %s was blocked by Amazon. Please try using better proxies\n"%url)
        else:
            print("Page %s must have been blocked by Amazon as the status code was %d"%(url,r.status_code))
        return None
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create
    return e.extract(r.text)


search_amazon(search_query) # <------ search query goes here.

# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('search_results.yml')

# product_data = []
output_file = open('{}_{}_results.jsonl'.format(search_query,date), "w+")
destination = 'results'

with open("search_results_urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('{}_{}_results.jsonl'.format(search_query,date),'w') as outfile:
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        data = scrape(url)
        if data:
            for product in data['products']:
                product['search_url'] = url
                print("Saving Product: %s"%product['title'].encode('utf8'))
                json.dump(product,outfile)
                outfile.write("\n")
                # sleep(5)

new_path = shutil.move('{}_{}_results.jsonl'.format(search_query, date), destination)

print("---DONE---")
print('\n')
```

To the above code I am getting the below error messages:

Getting error on line:-

```
items=wait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item s-asin")))
```

which says:-

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

search_results.yml File:

```
products:
    css: 'div[data-component-type="s-search-result"]'
    xpath: null
    multiple: true
    type: Text
    children:
        title:
            css: 'h2 a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'
            xpath: null
            type: Text
        url:
            css: 'h2 a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'
            xpath: null
            type: Link
        rating:
            css: 'div.a-row.a-size-small span:nth-of-type(1)'
            xpath: null
            type: Attribute
            attribute: aria-label
        reviews:
            css: 'div.a-row.a-size-small span:nth-of-type(2)'
            xpath: null
            type: Attribute
            attribute: aria-label
        price:
            css: 'span.a-price:nth-of-type(1) span.a-offscreen'
            xpath: null
            type: Text
```

search_results.txt

```
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&ref=nb_sb_noss
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&page=2&qid=1601905266&ref=sr_pg_1
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&page=3&qid=1601905268&ref=sr_pg_2
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&page=4&qid=1601905269&ref=sr_pg_3
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&page=5&qid=1601905269&ref=sr_pg_4
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Macbook+Pro&page=6&qid=1601905270&ref=sr_pg_5
```

The code above is for scraping the data from Amazon website using Selenium, to collect the data by entering any particular product name.

I tried most of the solutions by surfing from the internet and Youtube like adding '(By.)' for ID, and Class and so on, but nothing gave the required solution.
Please can anyone provide me with the required solution?.

Comment: Please share all your Selenium code including the link to the page you working on

Comment: I have updated the code, please take a look at it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to Pagination.

```
    `next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a-last > a")`
```

this code is used to find the next page button